# Exclude files from type: module without changing file extension

Tags: javascript, package.json, es6-modules

I had to set `"type": "module"` in my `package.json` file and I would like to exclude some files from being treated as ES module files but WITHOUT changing its extension, as I need to keep it as `.js` file because other server scripts, (which I cannot change) points directly to that specific `filename.js` file and not `.cjs` or any other extension - is it possible via some config files?

Comment: *"as I need to keep it as .js file because other server scripts, (which I cannot change) points directly to that specific filename.js file'* Would you show an example of what you mean by "points directly to"? (A real one from the code where you're having trouble.) It's hard to answer the question without knowing what you're really doing, and thus what we're really trying to help you solve. (And how are those server scripts run?)

Comment: unfortunately no, it's a jenkins script that is using that file to generate other manifest files etc. Not sure if it's that relevant really to the question - I just need to keep that `.js` file "as it is" in my project, but with switching to `type:module` at the same time.

Comment: No, AFAIK it's not possible. `*.js` files are either ES modules or CJS modules, depending on the `type` value in `package.json`. The file extension is the only way to change the module type for single files.

Comment: @lukaszkups - Yes, it's possible to provide those deatils, and yes, it's relevant to answering the question. If you're not willing to provide the necessary details, I'm afraid we can't help you. Good luck with it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, for what you've described you only have a couple of options (some of which, or possibly all of which, may not work for your specific situation):

- Don't use `"type": "module"` (so the files that have to be CommonJS remain CommonJS) and instead rename the files you want handled via ESM to `.mjs`.
- Ensure that a different `package.json` applies to the files you want handled as CommonJS modules, for instance by putting them in a `scripts` subdirectory with a `package.json` that has `{"type": "commonjs"}` in it. (But if you can't change the file extensions on the files to `.cjs`, you probably can't move them to another folder.)
- Create your own module loader that delegates the loading of these files to the CommonJS loader while loading others via ESM. (Not a small thing, but not impossible either; [here's an example of one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm)from back before Node itself supported ESM.)